# right and left borders appears on top of the top border

Tags: css, border

As you can se here: http://jsfiddle.net/vpHW5/
the right and left borders appears on top of the top border. How would I fix that?

Here's the css code:

```
div {
    background:#e8e3dd;
    border-right:1px solid #e3ded8;
    border-left:1px solid #e3ded8;
    border-top:4px solid #172e4e;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Does this help understand it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vpHW5/6/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second what @Curt says - though you can get the desired behaviour by overlaying an absolutely positioned pseudo-element on the div:

```
div {
    background: #e8e3dd;
    border-top: 4px solid #172e4e;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; top: 0px; left: 0; right: 0;
    border-right: 4px solid khaki;
    border-left: 4px solid khaki; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpHW5/2/

Comment: Just curious, can you just inherit the border color, width and style from the parent of the pseudo element and to reduce some maintenance?

Comment: @MarcAudet: Unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the borders that are coming up the sides you can follow @Curts advice

Stick a div at the top with the following

```
div {
    background:#e8e3dd;
    border-right:1px solid #e3ded8;
    border-left:1px solid #e3ded8;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.divheader {
    height:4px;
    background:#000000;
    margin: 0 -1px 0 -1px 0; /*This tells the header div to overlap the borders on left and right the negative values match those of your border widths*/
}

<div><div class="divheader"></div></div>
```

That should do the trick